# Show spring form errors inside an ExtJS 4 window

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

I have a Ext JS Window with a spring form of user details. Additionally, I have an user validator in my controller, so that, if the form has errors i can see what errors are:

```
UserValidator userValidator = new UserValidator();
userValidator.validate(user, result);
if(result.hasErrors()){
    return "RegisterUserForm";
```

My problem is relative to have this form inside a ExtJS window. If i return "RegisterUserForm" the browser goes to this form and show the errors but not in the window. It shows the form and errors in a new page and the url changes to /RegisterUserForm. (This is obvious) How can i show the same form with errors without having this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Change your server code to make that an AJAX call that returns only the *data* to be handled by your ExtJS code, rather than a form page
2. Make your `Ext.window.Window` use an iFrame with the `/RegisterUserForm` url:

ex:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    layout: 'fit',
    //other config here
    items: [{
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            itemId: 'iframe',
            tag: 'iframe',
            src: '/RegisterUserForm',
            frameBorder: 0
        }
    }]
}).show()
```

Comment: The iframe works for me. Thank you so much @kevhender. By the way.. the other alternative is return jsondata and do it with an extjs form?

Comment: There would be several ways to handle the JSON data, depending on the number of errors you expect and how you wish to format them.  With lots of errors with multiple columns, you could use a `Ext.grid.Panel`; with fewer errors and not as much info, you could use a `Ext.view.View`, or even just a plain old `Ext.Component`, that uses a `tpl` config to format the individual errors.

Comment: aha.. @kevhender My controller returns a json text when the submit is successuf. Is it possible to catch it with the iframe or i have to considerate to do an ext form to do this?

Comment: The iFrame will only work to show the URL that you specify with the `src` config option.  You could do some conditional logic to choose whether to add the iFrame component if there are errors, or to add a different component on success.

Comment: and.. The RegisterUserForm sends the data to the RegisterUser controller. This controller returns the form if there are errors or return the success message in json format whether to save the user. How can i get this response if it's "internal" to the iframe? Thank you @kevhender

Comment: You won't be able to access the contents of the iFrame from the containing app.  You should really handle success and failure responses the same way in this case.